# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de obtener el valor máximo de un campo integer?

Tags: php, pdo

Una tabla tiene un campo ID integer (no es autoincremental), deseo obtener el último valor para incrementarlo en los nuevos registros que se ingresarán.
Si la tabla no tiene registros $valorId=0.
Si la tabla tiene registros debe tomar el valor obtenido del select max(id).

```
$sql = "SELECT max(id) as valorId FROM tabla";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$valor   = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$valorId = $valor['valorId'];

if (is_null($valorId)){
    $valorId = 0;
}

if (is_string($valorId)){
    $valorId = intval($valorId);
}

echo $valorId;
```

El resultado que se obtiene de $valorId es:
Si no hay registros el tipo es NULL.
Si hay registros el tipo es string.
Esto funciona. Se puede mejorar?

Comment: los valores que obtienes no son numeros, por eso no obtienes el mayor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin importar los datos que haya o no haya en tu tabla, la consulta:

```
SELECT max(id) as valorId FROM tabla
```

... siempre resultará en ***exactamente 1 registro***.

Por ejemplo, si tu tabla está vacía, el resultado será ***1 registro*** con el valor `NULL`.

Y si la tabla sí contiene registros, el resultado será ***1 registro*** con el valor máximo de `id`.

Puedes confirmar esto aquí: <kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/IFOR62449)</kbd>.

De modo que no tiene ningún sentido que verifiques la cantidad de registros que te devuelve la consulta, ya que siempre te devolverá 1 registro.

Si deseas que te devuelva el valor `0` si la tabla está vacía, puedes agregar `coalesce` o `nullif` a la consulta:

```
SELECT coalesce(max(id), 0) as valorId FROM tabla
```

---

El otro punto que hay que esclarecer, es lo que pides en el título de tu pregunta:

> ¿Por qué el select no muestra la ***cantidad de registros*** de la consulta?

Si lo que quieres en realidad es la cantidad de registros, y no el valor `id` máximo, entonces la consulta no es correcta. Debería ser:

```
select count(*) from tabla
```

Obviamente, no sé cómo está definido tu columna `id`, pero lo veo sumamente improbable que el valor máximo de esa columna siempre corresponda exactamente a la cantidad de registros en la tabla.